# Laravel session handling to redirect without login

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have a login form and when user logins only it should open the page i.e if the user directly enters url it should redirect back to login page. 
In laravel i read there is Auth::check() but i am using auth.php for different login and that is working fine. but i created new login page since i cant use auth.php how can i proceed to see if session is set or not , if not redirect to login page in laravel;

```
<?php
class TelecallController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {
       $this->beforeFilter(function () {
            if(!Session::has('telecall_id'))
            {
             return Redirect::to('/8032/telecalls/login');
            }
        }, array('except' => array('')));
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following error

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Comment: check Auth::user() what you get in it?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is quite simple, look:

```
if(!Session::has('telecall_id'))
{
   return Redirect::to('/8032/telecalls/login');
}
```

Result of this `!Session::has('telecall_id')` is TRUE at the beginning.
When you go to `return Redirect::to('/8032/telecalls/login');` you made no changes in session value of `telecall_id` that is why you are redirected again and again.

After redirection you need to be sure that result of  `if(!Session::has('telecall_id'))` is FALSE. So that - you need to set session value properly.

Here you have how to prepare session properly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Comment: can u plz explain with one example